# Is it possible to create an Attached Property on a Sealed XAML control class?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps

The Run class in the Windows Store Apps libraries is SEALED, unlike the old desktop version. I need to add a property to it that I can retrieve when the user selects the Run.

Is it possible to attach a property to the sealed Run class that I can access in code?

Here is my attempt:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty MyIndexProperty =
    DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("MyIndex", typeof(int), typeof(Run), new PropertyMetadata(null));

public static int GetMyIndex(Run obj)
{
    return (int)obj.GetValue(MyIndexProperty);
}

public static void SetMyIndex(Run obj, int value)
{
    obj.SetValue(MyIndexProperty, value);
}
```

Comment: Do you have a problem with your attempt?

Comment: Yes. Trying to access Run.MyIndex in my C# code won't compile. The code is in the same namespace.

Comment: [Dependency Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh920267.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The C# *language* does not support "extension" or "attached" properties.

Attached properties are a WPF feature which affect XAML and the WPF binding system.
The only way to use a WPF attached property in code is to write `YourClass.SetMyIndex(instance, value);`.

There is no way to accomplish what you want, although extension methods can come close.

Comment: Thanks. Wish they had added a Tag or something on the Run. I will have to come up with another solution to identify them, like use the Name field or something. Our app is displaying numbered verses of text that need to be identified when the user selects them so that we can display associated media, etc.